# how to get one part of the string

Tags: c#, string

I have a string 
eg.

```
string a =  "OU=QALevel1,DC=CopTest,DC=copiun2,DC=com";
```

now i want my temp string to have the value

```
 tempString = "DC=CopTest,DC=copiun2,DC=com"
```

I need to remove all occurrences of the `OU` value pairs from the strings. These *always* appear first in the string.

Comment: What rules do you use to determine which part of the string you want?

Comment: Do you just want all the values that start with `DC`? And are you sure you want the output as a string? If you want to parse it further, it would make sense to this task and the further parsing in one step.

Comment: there can be other OU too.. that is just an example like it can be also OU=SupportSubLevel3,OU=SupportLevel1,DC=CopTest,DC=copiun2,DC=com

Comment: the OU's always come first and then the DC's come... i want to start where it starts with DC=

Comment: Then explain **exactly** what possible inputs you expect and what output you want. We can't guess from a single example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, it depends on what *grounds* you want it to be that. If you want everything after the first comma, you could use:

```
int comma = a.IndexOf(',');
if (comma != -1)
{
    string tempString = a.Substring(comma + 1);
    // Use tempString
}
else
{
    // Deal with there not being any commas
}
```

If that's not how you want to split the string, please give more information about what you need to do.

EDIT: If you need "the first comma followed by DC=" you can change the first line to:

```
int comma = a.IndexOf(",DC=");
```

Again, if you need something else, please be *much* more specific about what you're trying to do.

Comment: there can be other OU too.. that is just an example like it can be also OU=SupportSubLevel3,OU=SupportLevel1,DC=CopTest,DC=copiun2,DC=com

Comment: @user175084: So what determines where you want to start taking the string?

Answer (score 3):

You could use LINQ to help:

```
string foo = "OU=SupportSubLevel3,OU=SupportLevel1,DC=CopTest,DC=copiun2,DC=com";

string sub = string.Join(",", 
                         foo.Split(',')
                            .Where(x => x.StartsWith("DC")));
Console.WriteLine(sub);
```

- split the string into an array, on the commas
- take only those starting with DC
- put back into a string, separate each with a comma

Comment: `string.Split()` worked like this at least [since .Net 1.1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa904305%28v=VS.71%29.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

I suspect what you actually need here is all the domain components. You might even want to split them. This example will support any DN syntax, and extract the DC's from it:

```
string a = "OU=QALevel1,DC=CopTest,DC=copiun2,DC=com";

// Separate to parts
string[] parts = a.Split(',');

// Select the relevant parts
IEnumerable<string> dcs = parts.Where(part => part.StartsWith("DC="));

// Join them again
string result = string.Join(",", dcs);
```

Note that you get both `dcs` - an enumeration of all the DC parts, and `result` - the string you requested. But most importantly, this code *makes sense* - when you see it, you know exactly what it will do - return a string with a list of all the `DC=*` parts of the original string, removing any non-DC parts.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use the Substring function for this, but how you use it depends on your criteria. For example, you could just do this:

```
tempString = a.Substring(12);
```

If you could let us know you're criteria that'd be very useful

Comment: Or as @Jon Skeet has done basing your substring on the index of the first comma :)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the `OU` is always before the rest of the value pairs, this will get you all of the string following the last `OU` value:

```
string a =  "OU=QALevel1,DC=CopTest,DC=copiun2,DC=com";
string res = a.Substring(a.IndexOf(',', a.LastIndexOf("OU=")) + 1);

// res = "DC=CopTest,DC=copiun2,DC=com"
```