# How to read part of string from .txt file?

Tags: c#, file

Here is my problem, I have to read a certain data from the Text file.

For example: `"test1.txt"` has some data like

```
TEST1ZE  G P 1 -   ‘ 
 =  =    û   ¡  É É    
END1=  =    û  TEST2  ¡  É É ‘END2
```

I have to read data from TEST2 TO END2 in **c#**
later I have to convert this data in a byte array.

Comment: so....what have you tried and where are you getting stuck? (hint: show us some code)

Comment: Please read [FAQ] and [ask] a couple of times..

Comment: I am new to C# and don't know where to start.

Comment: Although its name is `test1.txt`, it doesn't seem to be a text file.

Comment: This is Q&A forum. You didn't ask a question - there can't be a good answer

Comment: really guys, like u never was in his position. downvotes dont help him, it doesn't help stackoverlow at all...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/db5x7c0d.aspx
this may help you, rest is logic in C#. you can find help here:
[how to get one part of the string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5844055/how-to-get-one-part-of-the-string)